# Targetting LI with specific class then hiding all other LIs

Tags: jquery

I have a UL of LIs in HTML like so:

```
<ul class="example">
<li class="class1"><a href="#"><img src="images/01.jpg" width="980" height="400" /></a></li>
<li class="class2 class1"><a href="#"><img src="images/02.jpg" width="980" height="400" /></a></li>
<li class="class3"><a href="#"><img src="images/03.jpg" width="980" height="400" /></a></li>
<li class="class1"><a href="#"><img src="images/04.jpg" width="980" height="400" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to use jQuery to select all of the LIs which do not have the class "Class1" and remove them from view. How can I do this? I thought the below should work but it does not seem to be working?

```
$("ul.example:not(li.class1)").hide();
```

Comment: $("ul.example li:not( .class1 )" ).hide();  // CSS for performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
$("ul.example li").not('.class1').hide();
```

[.not documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Also, as other have suggested, you could also use the [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/G9uhb/1/)

Comment: Anyway of removing the non .class1 LIs from the HTML rather than to hide them?

Comment: @dubbs yes, use .remove();

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("ul.example li:not(.class1)").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.example > li:not(.class1)').hide();
```